# Declare const in Qt and access from 2 different classes

Tags: c++, qt

I develop in Qt5 and want some advice.

I want to declare const variable in one class and use this variable in other classes.
what is the best way to do that?

Now i get error in my code:

protocolcommands.cpp

```
const QString CNT_FIRMWARE_ACK = "ACK";
const QString CNT_FIRMWARE_NAK = "NAK";
const QString CNT_FIRMWARE_NYET = "NYET";
const QString CNT_FIRMWARE_STALL = "STALL";
const QString CNT_FIRMWARE_HEARTBEAT = "HEARTBEAT";

QString ProtocolCommands::parseCommand(QByteArray ba)
{

    QString s;
    if (ba[2] == 0x02)
    {
        s = "flow control";
        if (ba[3] == 0x01 && ba[4] == 0x01)
          return CNT_FIRMWARE_ACK;
        if (ba[3] == 0x01 && ba[4] == 0x02)
          return CNT_FIRMWARE_NAK;
        if (ba[3] == 0x01 && ba[4] == 0x03)
          return CNT_FIRMWARE_STALL;
        if (ba[3] == 0x01 && ba[4] == 0x04)
          return CNT_FIRMWARE_NYET;
    }
    else if (ba[2] == 0x03)
    {
        s = "data packet";
        qDebug() << ba.toHex();
        if (ba[3] == 0x1a && ba[4] == 0x02)
         return "getJsonStringFor_GetStimulatorOperaionType";

    }
    else if (ba[2] == 0x04)
    {
          return CNT_FIRMWARE_HEARTBEAT;
    }
   // return "";
}
```

engine.cpp:

```
void Engine::onSerialArrivedMsg(QByteArray msg)
{
ProtocolCommands pc;
qDebug() << "somthing has arrived : " << msg.toHex();
//if we here - this is new message from the firmware
//this function refer just to one message at a time

//first check if we are in the middle of flow:
if (mode)
{
     qDebug() << "mode = true";
     switch (curr_step_in_flow) {
     case 1:  //last command send to FW was [Set SinglePulse Parameters]
         if (pc.parseCommand(msg) == ProtocolCommands::CNT_FIRMWARE_ACK)    // compile eror
         {
            qDebug() << "ack recieved";
            curr_step_in_flow = 2;
         }
         else if (pc.parseCommand(msg) == CNT_FIRMWARE_HEARTBEAT ) // compile error
         {
             //heartbeat msg
             //send signal to the heartbeat thread
             emit fwHeartBeatArrived();
         }
         break;
     default:
         break;
     }

}
else
{
   if (pc.parseCommand(msg) == CNT_FIRMWARE_HEARTBEAT)  // compile eror
   {
       //heartbeat msg
       //send signal to the heartbeat thread
       emit fwHeartBeatArrived();
   }

}

}
```

Comment: What error do you have exactly? You also should return something instead of `// return "";` - your code is incorrect because the `control reaches end of non-void function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to declare const variable in one class and use this variable in other classes.

Those strings aren't part of your `ProtocolCommands` class; they just happen to be declared in that compilatition unit.

If you want them as (static) members of the class, then declare them inside the declaration of the `ProtocolCommands` class in protocolcommands.h:

```
class ProtocolCommands {
public:
   static const QString CNT_FIRMWARE_ACK;
   // ...
};
```

And then initialize them in protocolcommands.cpp:

```
const QString ProtocolCommands::CNT_FIRMWARE_ACK = "ACK";
```

And then you can refer to it in any code that includes protocolcommands.h by the name `ProtocolCommands::CNT_FIRMWARE_ACK`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with using an `enum` type instead of declaring my constants as strings. So, the `ProtocolCommands` class will look like:

```
class ProtocolCommands
{
public:
    enum Type {
        CNT_FIRMWARE_ACK,
        CNT_FIRMWARE_NAK,
        CNT_FIRMWARE_NYET,
        CNT_FIRMWARE_STALL,
        CNT_FIRMWARE_HEARTBEAT    
    };

    ProtocolCommands::Type parseCommand(const QByteArray &ba);
    [..]
};
```

So, your `ProtocolCommands::parseCommand()` should return an integer value instead of a string. Thus your `Engine::onSerialArrivedMsg(QByteArray msg)` function will look like:

```
void Engine::onSerialArrivedMsg(QByteArray msg)
{
    ProtocolCommands pc;
    [..]
    switch (pc.parseCommand(msg)) {    
    case ProtocolCommands::CNT_FIRMWARE_ACK:
    [..]
    case ProtocolCommands::CNT_FIRMWARE_NYET:
    [..]
    }
 }
```

The benefits of using this approach are:

- It is faster, as you need to compare numbers and not strings,
- The design is much simple and clearer as you don't need to deal with global or static variables.

Comment: Why are you insisting the author of the question to use enums? Maybe he really needs strings? However this makes sense, this does not answer the question on `How to declare const variable in one class and use in another.` Simply, your `enum`'s values are not a constant variables.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy, first of all, I don't insist anyone to follow my recommendations. Secondly - there is no engineering reasons to use strings instead of integers (at least author doesn't mention any), thirdly - enum values **are constants**.

Comment: Of course enum values are constants, but not a variables (or objects, for example) as author mentioned. Author wants to use variables. You may not see any reasons to use strings here, yes, but maybe the question is not related only to this code snippet you see in his question, maybe the author just need to know exactly `how to declare constant variables inside a class and use them in another?`.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy, he wants to know `how to declare constant variables inside a class and use them in another`? I have answered this question. I don't see a requirement to use only "string variables". In you comments you used word "maybe" 3 times. You could ask the OP and post your answer and prove that it is better than other's instead of guessing.

Comment: `I want to declare const variable in one class and use this variable in other classes. what is the best way to do that?` - this is a quote of what the author of the question wants to know, while you answer on `How to declare enum inside a class and use it?` or `What is the best way to have scalar constants inside a class?` or something like that. Can't you see the difference in these questions? I still don't agree with you when you say you did answer the question because your answer is more **recommendation-like** instead of solving the author's problem.

Comment: In which way my answer does not solve the problem? Besides it is much efficient than using global string constants. Thus I find you objections pointless.

Comment: It is much efficient, I agree, but author did not ask you for the efficiency, obviously, he asked about **how to implement it** but not a **best way of replacing it with something**. Just suppose the author have a `QRexExp` instead of `QString`, for example. Does your "solution" answers his question?

Answer (score 0):

Define yours constants at `ProtocolCommands.h` file or include `.cpp` files as additional (bad-smells style). Then you can refer to them as constants like

```
pc.parseCommand(msg) == CNT_FIRMWARE_HEARTBEAT
```

This is because you include only header file, but header has no idea about constants you want to use.